# Check if dataframe has records or not in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using if(df.count)>0 then execute code otherwise end the job.
But we know count is action and in glue job it is very heavy operation.

Instead of this which option Can I use in pyspark?

Comment: You could use `head()`, then check if that is non-zero length

Comment: I tried if(len(df.head(1))>1 but it is giving me error as typerror:object of type dataframe has no len().

Can you suggest me other option?

Comment: `head` returns a dataframe, so you still would use `.count`, not `len()`. it'll just be faster than counting the whole dataframe. Also, `> 0`, or `>= 1` would check has records, not `> 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if not df.rdd.isEmpty():
    #your code
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [], schema =  StructType([]))
df.show()

if df.head():
    print('Data is Available')
    # Required Code
else:
    print("No data present")
```

[image]

[image]